# Best way to maintain voicing in this example, without awkwardness

Tags: fingering

I have tried this with crossing the LH over, and under, to hit the A# indicated by the arrow; have also tried playing the A# with RH. The latter is much easier but makes it incredibly hard to maintain the voicing. The former is very awkward. Hoping that maybe someone is near a piano and could try this measure out, to offer an opinion of what approach I should take. Seems like it shouldn't be that difficult, but for some reason, it is just giving me trouble. Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use RH only.
You need preparation of finger **5** playing the A-sharp.
This can be done by **5** hovering over G-sharp when **2** plays B. Can get better preparation by angling the hand (*see photo*) and then **3** or **4** depending on what’s next.
I’d favour **4** because it’s less physically possible to play legato with **4** than **3**, to detach from the high A-sharp.
[image: angling hand on piano]